# Linked Objects with different materials

Tags: modeling, materials, blend-files, linked-data

I am making my own asset library. I want to prepare everything for Cycles and for Luxrender in different files. To avoid two different Objects I need some way to keep the Data in both files the same except the material, because I need to adjust the materials for Luxrender and Cycles separately.
Is there an easy way to only unlink the materials or so?
Modifiers, Armatures, eg. should stay all the same!

Comment: See [my answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80821/what-does-this-icon-mean-circle-next-to-a-child-in-blender/80824?noredirect=1#comment142460_80824) materials can be assigned to *Object* or *Object Data* in your case make a master file with the geometry only then link the objects from there and override materials locally.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos thanks for your answer. But i have tried every setting but the material menu is still greyed out...

Comment: Select a linked object, press `L` > *Make Local > Selected Objects*