# What does this icon mean - circle next to a child in blender

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, blend-files

I would like to know what the circle icon next to Body_M_Georndr.005 means and why it is not next to part_Kidney_Right since they are both children of the same parent

[image]

Comment: Circle next to "Body_M_Georndr.005" shows that material is assigned to that mesh. It's not visible on the image if they are children of the same parent but assigning materials isn't related to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the icon of a *Material* datablock, it means there is a material assigned directly to the mesh data, as opposed to the object itself.

When creating or editing *Material Slots* you have two options when assigning a material, it can be either assigned to the *Object* or the *Object Data*.

When assigned to the object, several object clones or instances of that object (while sharing the same geometry or mesh data) can have different materials regardless, but if the material is assigned to the *Object Data* all instances will forcefully have that same material.

Each materials assigned to *Object Data* will display one additional icon to the side of the data it is bound to in the *Outliner*, other materials show up below.

[image: Materials in Outliner]